# Adjusting default node spacing in Tikz with the `bayesnet` package?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the tikz library `bayesnet`, and can't seem to figure out how to control the default node spacing. I assume because `bayesnet` overrides the default node style. You can see this below: Tikz nodes respond to the `node distance=5mm` configuration option, but the node styles `latent` and `obs` from `bayesnet` ignore this, and have a large spacing:

[image: bayenetnodespacing]

```latex
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
    \node[circle] (a) {a};
    \node[latent,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
    \node[circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
    \node[obs,circle,right=of c] (d) {d};%
    \edge {a} {b};
    \edge {b} {c};
    \edge {c} {d};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm hoping there is a simple (uncluttered) way of controlling the default spacing of all nodes when using Tikz+bayesnet? Other questions about node spacing in general don't seem to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION 1** You can shorten the arrows by moving the end node (or see option 2).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{test}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
            \node[circle] (a) {a};
            \node[latent,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
            \node[circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
            \node[obs,circle,right=of c] (d) {d};%
            \edge {a} {b};
            \edge {b} {c};
            \edge {c} {d};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
        \node[circle] (a) {a};
        \node[latent,circle,right=of a,  xshift=-0.5cm] (b) {b};% changed<<<<
        \node[circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
        \node[obs,circle,right=of c,  xshift=-0.5cm] (d) {d};%changed<<<<
        \edge {a} {b};
        \edge {b} {c};
        \edge {c} {d};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**OPTION 2** redefine the style `latent` globally or locally changing the  `node distance`  The style `obs` will change accordingly.

```
        \tikzstyle{latent} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,
            minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont, node distance=0.5]
```

,

```
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}


\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{test}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
            \node[circle] (a) {a};
            \node[latent,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};%
            \node[circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
            \node[obs,circle,right=of c] (d) {d};%
            \edge {a} {b};
            \edge {b} {c};
            \edge {c} {d};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzstyle{latent} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,
            minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont, node distance=0.5]
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
        \node[circle] (a) {a};
        \node[latent,circle,right=of a] (b) {b};
        \node[circle,right=of b] (c) {c};%
        \node[obs,circle,right=of c] (d) {d};
        \edge {a} {b};
        \edge {b} {c};
        \edge {c} {d};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle{latent} = [circle,fill=white,draw=black,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=20pt, font=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont,node distance=0.5]` is the way to go. thanks.